# Adding custom menu item to BlackBerry "documents to go" app

Tags: blackberry, java-me

Is it possible to add a custom menu item, such as "print", that can perform my specific task in the "documents to go" application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK you can not add menu item to 3rd party app.